# Go-Ethereum | How to connect to public Ropsten(testnet) running on local

Tags: rpc, go-ethereum, geth, bitcoin-testnet, evm

Basically I want to connect to the public Ropsten testnet. I run geth on local with several options. `(--testnet, --rpc, --rpcapi, console)`.

I thought I can get my (ropsten) account and check how much 'ether' or 'erc20 tokens' that I have on ropsten testnet. 
However, it didn't recognize the ether that my account had.

For example, I successfully sent some 'ether' and 'custom erc20 tokens' to my account using "ethereum wallet". I could see the correct amounts on metamask when I connected to 'Ropsten Test Network' to click the dropdown bar at top of the metamask window.
However, If I changed it to the 'Localhost 8545' which is 4th of dropdown bar and connect to the 'localhost:8545', the ether and tokens changed to 0 amount.

Not the same amount which is weird. In conclusion, I think that the geth running on my local is not connected to public ropsten testnet network. Because it means I have different private key with same public address. The same public address on ropsten testnet has to have equal private key, I think.

Does anyone have same experience like this or can I get any idea how to (geth)command to connect to the public testnet network.

oh, and I have another issue!

I run the go-ethereum on local like below.

```
$ geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi "db, net, web3, personal" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddir 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 console
```

but I can't connect to localhost:8545 on metamask anymore.

```
netstat -na | grep -i LISTEN
netstat -na | grep -i LISTEN | grep 8545
```

I can't find the 8545 opened port. 
Why the rpc port is not open sometimes?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would like to tell you that you don't need to specify "rpcport" parameter incase you want to start node on 8545, By default it starts on port 8454.
Now for the question regarding the balancing which is not visible when you connect to localhost:8545 on metamask. I would like to ask for how long you have been running ropsten using local geth. I have doubt whether it is fully synced or not.
Try running these commands in the new terminal-

    `geth attach
    eth.syncing`

it will provide you with the following info-:
1. Current block number
2. Total block height
If total block height is greater the the current block number, than it means your node is not fully synced and is still syncing.

Comment: The 'warn' keywords were kept showing up on screen and threw / discard the blocks when the synchronization was in progress. So I thought the syncing was ended. Yep I will compare my block number and total block height. Thank you for your advice!